# SQL Server query for top clients before 2017 that haven't been Invoiced since 2017

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

I am trying to write a query to list the Top 200 clients from years < 2017 that haven't had any invoiced amounts since 2017.

I have tried a few variations of the query, but keep coming up with 0 results, which I know is inaccurate by default but I've got the right information in Excel. I haven't had much experience in sub-queries and saw an opportunity to work through one.

```
SELECT TOP 200
    SUM(OI.OrderInvoiceTotalAmount) AS 'Invoiced',
    O.Deal,
    CASE
       WHEN O.Location LIKE '%Vegas%' THEN 'Las Vegas'
        WHEN O.Location LIKE '%New%' THEN 'New Jersey'
        WHEN O.Location LIKE '%Orange%' THEN 'Los Angeles'
        WHEN O.Location LIKE '%Angeles%' THEN 'Los Angeles'
        WHEN O.Location LIKE '%Angeles%' AND O.OrderType = 'System' THEN 'Las Vegas'
        WHEN O.Location LIKE '%DC%' THEN 'Washington DC'
        WHEN O.Location LIKE '%DC%' AND O.OrderType = 'System' THEN 'New Jersey'
        WHEN O.Location LIKE '%Nashville%' THEN 'Tennessee'
        WHEN O.Location LIKE '%Nashville%' AND O.OrderType = 'System' THEN 'Las Vegas'
        WHEN O.Location LIKE '%Houston%' THEN 'Houston'
        WHEN O.Location LIKE '%Orlando%' THEN 'Orlando'
        WHEN O.Location LIKE 'Penn%' THEN 'Pennsylvania'
        WHEN O.Location='Enterprises' THEN 'Entertainment'
        ELSE O.Location
    END AS 'Location'
FROM 
    dbo.OrderInvoice as OI
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.Orders as O ON O.OrderKey = OI.OrderKey
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.Invoice as I on I.InvoiceKey = OI.InvoiceKey
WHERE 
    O.Status NOT IN ('Snapshot', 'Cancelled', 'Void')
    AND I.InvoiceStatusCode <> 'Estimate'
    AND I.InvoiceType = 'Billing'
    AND Year(I.InvoiceDate) < '2017'
    AND O.Deal NOT LIKE '%4Wall%'
    AND O.Location LIKE '%Nashville%'
GROUP BY
    O.Deal,
    CASE
        WHEN O.Location LIKE '%Vegas%' THEN 'Las Vegas'
        WHEN O.Location LIKE '%New%' THEN 'New Jersey'
        WHEN O.Location LIKE '%Orange%' THEN 'Los Angeles'
        WHEN O.Location LIKE '%Angeles%' THEN 'Los Angeles'
        WHEN O.Location LIKE '%Angeles%' AND O.OrderType = 'System' THEN 'Las Vegas'
        WHEN O.Location LIKE '%DC%' THEN 'Washington DC'
        WHEN O.Location LIKE '%DC%' AND O.OrderType = 'System' THEN 'New Jersey'
        WHEN O.Location LIKE '%Nashville%' THEN 'Tennessee'
        WHEN O.Location LIKE '%Nashville%' AND O.OrderType = 'System' THEN 'Las Vegas'
        WHEN O.Location LIKE '%Houston%' THEN 'Houston'
        WHEN O.Location LIKE '%Orlando%' THEN 'Orlando'
        WHEN O.Location LIKE 'Penn%' THEN 'Pennsylvania'
        WHEN O.Location = 'Enterprises' THEN 'Entertainment'
        ELSE O.Location
    END
HAVING
    (SELECT SUM(OI.OrderInvoiceTotalAmount)
     FROM dbo.OrderInvoice as OI
     INNER JOIN dbo.Invoice as I on OI.InvoiceKey=I.InvoiceKey
     INNER JOIN dbo.Orders as O on OI.OrderKey=O.OrderKey
     WHERE YEAR(I.InvoiceDate) > '2017' 
       AND I.InvoiceStatusCode <> 'Estimate'
       AND I.InvoiceType = 'Billing'
       AND O.Deal NOT LIKE '%4Wall%'
       AND O.Location LIKE '%Nashville%') = 0
```

Let me know if I need to add more info.

Thanks good people

Comment: Unrelated: `When O.Location Like '%Angeles%' Then 'Los Angeles' When O.Location Like '%Angeles%' AND O.OrderType='System' Then 'Las Vegas'` will never return `'Las Vegas'` as the first case matches those with `O.OrderType='System'` too. Put the more specific case first or add `AND O.OrderType<>'System'` to the less specific one. (Analog for `'%Nashville%'` and `'%DC%'`.)

Comment: Shoot! That's right, dag. Thanks @stickybit

Comment: Just say  Having  Sum(OI.OrderInvoiceTotalAmount)  =  0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When checking for missing rows, use `NOT EXISTS`, is faster than actually doing a `COUNT` and checking if it's 0 or not (the engine has to count all rows before comparing). I've commented the lines I edited. Basically removed the `HAVING` and added a `NOT EXISTS` on the `WHERE`.

```
Select TOP 200
Sum(OI.OrderInvoiceTotalAmount) as 'Invoiced',
O.Deal,
Case
    When O.Location Like '%Vegas%' Then 'Las Vegas'
    When O.Location Like '%New%' Then 'New Jersey'
    When O.Location Like '%Orange%' Then 'Los Angeles'
    When O.Location Like '%Angeles%' Then 'Los Angeles'
    When O.Location Like '%Angeles%' AND O.OrderType='System' Then 'Las Vegas'
    When O.Location Like '%DC%' Then 'Washington DC'
    When O.Location Like '%DC%' AND O.OrderType='System' Then 'New Jersey'
    When O.Location Like '%Nashville%' Then 'Tennessee'
    When O.Location Like '%Nashville%' AND O.OrderType='System' Then 'Las Vegas'
    When O.Location Like '%Houston%' Then 'Houston'
    WHen O.Location Like '%Orlando%' Then 'Orlando'
    When O.Location Like 'Penn%' Then 'Pennsylvania'
    When O.Location='Enterprises' Then 'Entertainment'
    Else O.Location
End as 'Location'

From dbo.OrderInvoice as OI
Inner Join dbo.Orders as O on O.OrderKey=OI.OrderKey
Inner Join dbo.Invoice as I on I.InvoiceKey=OI.InvoiceKey

Where O.Status Not In ('Snapshot','Cancelled','Void')
AND I.InvoiceStatusCode<>'Estimate'
AND I.InvoiceType='Billing'
AND Year(I.InvoiceDate)<'2017'
AND O.Deal Not Like '%4Wall%'
AND O.Location Like '%Nashville%'

-- no record from 2017 must exist
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 
        'no record from 2017'
    From dbo.OrderInvoice as XOI -- Note that we use different alias here so it doesn't get mixed up
    Inner Join dbo.Invoice as XI on XOI.InvoiceKey=XI.InvoiceKey
    Inner Join dbo.Orders as XO on XOI.OrderKey=XO.OrderKey
    Where Year(XI.InvoiceDate)> 2017
        AND XI.InvoiceStatusCode<>'Estimate'
        AND XI.InvoiceType='Billing'
        AND XO.Deal Not Like '%4Wall%'
        AND XO.Location Like '%Nashville%'

        AND O.Deal = XO.Deal -- link between the outmost query and the correlated query
    )

Group By
O.Deal,
Case
    When O.Location Like '%Vegas%' Then 'Las Vegas'
    When O.Location Like '%New%' Then 'New Jersey'
    When O.Location Like '%Orange%' Then 'Los Angeles'
    When O.Location Like '%Angeles%' Then 'Los Angeles'
    When O.Location Like '%Angeles%' AND O.OrderType='System' Then 'Las Vegas'
    When O.Location Like '%DC%' Then 'Washington DC'
    When O.Location Like '%DC%' AND O.OrderType='System' Then 'New Jersey'
    When O.Location Like '%Nashville%' Then 'Tennessee'
    When O.Location Like '%Nashville%' AND O.OrderType='System' Then 'Las Vegas'
    When O.Location Like '%Houston%' Then 'Houston'
    WHen O.Location Like '%Orlando%' Then 'Orlando'
    When O.Location Like 'Penn%' Then 'Pennsylvania'
    When O.Location='Enterprises' Then 'Entertainment'
    Else O.Location
End
```

I'm assuming that the link for the correlated query is through `Deal` column.

Comment: Cools, new item to use! Thanks @EZlo, that worked great.

Comment: Oh yeah, and thank you for the extra note about when to use different aliases.